# Jenkins DSL plugin – cron triggering not generated

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-job-dsl

I’m using Jenkins DSL plugin to generate a Job that needed to be invoked periodically
All was going as expected – only the triggering cron that was supposed to be generated by the code below was not displayed in the Job’s GUI, and the job is not triggered peridically
When I examined the actual generated job configuration file (config.xml) the cron text was there

Here is the code:

```
dslFactory.freeStyleJob(jobName+'-PeriodicInvocation') {
    triggers {
        cron("$cronVal")
     }
}
```

The value of  cronVal is fetched from a configuration file.

Using DSL version 1.39, Jenkins version 1.625 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but please write an actual question with a minimal example and provide an answer separately. If someone runs across this entry in the search results, they may skip right past it because no answers have been provided. As written, this is not a question and even if I read it as a question, it's unclear what input produced the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2):

The value of cron expression that was wrong (had 6 parts instead of 5) example: “H 22 ****”

Once the expression was fixed, the cron expression was visible in the configuration and the job invoked according to the expression.
An easy way to check the expression is to try the edit the generated job manually, with the cron expression, and try to save it. If it is wrong Jenkins will not allow it.